# Is there a way to obtain a number emitted by Observable<number> directly in html?

Tags: html, angular, observable, angular7

I'm looking for a way to have a number inside an Observable directly in html without subscribing Observable in ts file.

Searching on web I've found no conclusive answer.

```js
 number$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

 submitRandomNumber() {
   this.number$.next(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
 }
```

```html
  <p>{{ number$ }}</p>
  <button (click)="submitRandomNumber()">SubmitRandomNumber</button>
```

As expected result I want to see number changes on the page when button in pressed. Now I've only `[object Object]` printed on screen over button. Is there an html fix can I apply to html part to obtain number instead object?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **async**

Try `<p>{{ number$ | async}}</p>`

See: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rdkz5)